# Azure Mobile Services , should I use _deleted=false in each query/read

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

When we create a new table in Azure Mobile Services Data, it creates a [__deleted] column along with others like [__createdAt] etc. This is good, in case if I have to soft delete a record, I set _deleted = true, instead of permanently deleting it. 
My question is, when we query a MobileServices table say from client side or in server scripts using table.read or mssql.query, do I need to specify __deleted=false in each read/query explicitly or is there any app level config/setting available in MobileServices that we can set so that it doesn't return the records with __deleted=true by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, queries going through the standard path (formed via client or server table.read) should filter deleted records. (Essentially a __deleted = false clause will be added for you)

To get deleted records from the client you can send the __includeDeleted querystring parameter or on server you can use table.read({includeDeleted: true, ...) This will disable that default clause from being added.

Comment: great, thats what I thought , there has to be some internal mechanism to filter deleted record for me.  I hope it would work with mssql.query too.

Comment: How to include deleted records in iOS app (Azure) or in .net backend ?